# create model instance with nested serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Assume I have following database:

```
class A(models):
    b = ForeignKey(b)

class B(models):
    pass
```

For this I have serializers:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = A

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = B
```

If I do:

```
b = BSerializer(data=data) #with the data of A as well (ie: {'name':'test a', 'a':{'name':'test'}}
```

and:

```
b.save()
```

This scenario will try to save `A` as well, but what if `A` has a required foreign key to `B`, but `B` first needs to be created before it can be assigned.

Is it just better to give separate serializers instead of nesting in these cases, or is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way around this. Looking at this problem from the database level, this is a many to one relationship. B needs to be saved in the Db so that it has an id. In the db table of A there is a column called b_id where the id of B will be stored. So I think you need to save instance of B before relating it to instances of A.

Comment: i found that the problem is that django-rest framework does not support writable nested serializers. i did implement a relatively elegant custom solution to this though which makes use of the rest framework and this makes it possible to write everything in one request, as opposed to multiple. but in terms of using django-rest framework to solve this, as my question here is about, this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: but you're correct, ofcourse B needs to be saved first before A (which is required foreignkey) can assign reference to B.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the concept how you did it? I wasn't able to do it using django rest framework so I use django forms for post and put.

Comment: yes, using serializers and a more flexible rest view, such as APIView, then in post and put, do if serailizerA.is_valid etc... serializerB.is_valid etc..save serializerB, then before save of serializerA, you assign the relationship to the saved serializerB, access each object there, and then save serializerA. this works with many as well, since you would access the object once more. this can do in one request and returns errors nicely. very simple and maintainable way